# how to render an ejs template while looping over a document

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, ejs

i have set a route in using which i get all the emails registered under the 'users' collection in firestore database.
Inside this route, i am rendering an ejs template and want to show all the emails.

My route :

```
    app.get('/check',(request,response)=>{
  db.collection('users').get().then(snapshot=>{
         snapshot.docs.forEach(doc=>{
          response.render('check',{user: doc.data().email})
         })        
      })
  })
```

my ejs template:

```
<h1>check welcome</h1>
<ol>
    <li><%=  user  %></li>
</ol>
```

the template gets rendered but i am just getting the first email registered , rather than all.
In console, i am getting this errror :

```
>  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>      at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
>      at ServerResponse.header (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
>      at ServerResponse.send (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>      at done (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:10)
>      at tryHandleCache (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:278:5)
>      at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:478:10)
>      at View.render (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
>      at tryRender (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>      at Function.render (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>      at ServerResponse.render (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase 2.0/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
```

I will be grateful to any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the document, create a data structure in Javascript (probably an array) that you then pass to a single `res.render()` and your template then loops over the data to create something for each email.  You can only call `res.render()` once per request.